# UITableView проблемы с созданием Sections

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift4

У меня есть сингл тон в который записывайся данные когда пользователь выбирает продукт после чего я передаю эти данные в корзину и отображаю их

''' 
import UIKit

final class BasketModel {

```
static let shared = BasketModel()
var records: [Products] = []

private init() {}

func addProducts(_ product: Products) {
    self.records.append(product)

}

func clearProducts() {
    self.records = []
}
```

}

struct Products {

```
let img: UIImage
let name: String
let price: Int
let type: String
```

}
'''

У меня есть три продукта ( Блюда, Топпинги, Напитки) я хочу создать 3 секции с такими данными Блюда, Топпинги, Напитки вот мой код таблицы

'''
import UIKit

class BasketVC: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var fullBasketview: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomBasketView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var choiceBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var basketTableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var totalPriceLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var orderButton: UIButton!

var presenter = false
var totalPrice = 0

var sections: [String] = ["Блюда","Топпинги","Наппитки"]
var product = [BasketModel.shared.records]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    choiceBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    choiceBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true
    basketTableView.delegate = self
    basketTableView.dataSource = self
    orderButton.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    orderButton.layer.masksToBounds = true

    if !BasketModel.shared.records.isEmpty {

        fullBasketview.isHidden = false

        for item in BasketModel.shared.records {
            totalPrice += item.price
            totalPriceLabel.text = "\(totalPrice) Руб."
        }


    } else {

        fullBasketview.isHidden = true
    }

}

@IBAction func unwindBasketVC(for unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}
```

}

extension BasketVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return sections[section]

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return product[section].count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BasketCell", for: indexPath) as! BasketCell


    cell.basketImg.image = product[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].img
    cell.basketName.text = product[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].name
    cell.basketPrice.text = "\(product[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].price) Руб."

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {
        BasketModel.shared.records.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        totalPrice = 0
        for item in BasketModel.shared.records {
            totalPrice += item.price
            totalPriceLabel.text = "\(totalPrice) Руб."
        }
    }
    if BasketModel.shared.records.isEmpty {
        fullBasketview.isHidden = true 
    }
}


func  tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

}

'''

После того того как я перейду в корзину ошибка появляется тут 
'''
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

```
    return product[section].count -> Fatal error: Index out of range
}
```

'''

Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас несостыковка в логике вывода секций и продуктов внутри них - у вас 3 секции, но при этом вот здесь `var product = [BasketModel.shared.records]` `product` будет содержать лишь один вложенный массив со всеми продуктами без разделения на секции

Если у вас продукты идут единым массивом (скажем их 10 и они для разных секций), то вам надо их сначала рассортировать по какому-то признаку например `type` (что отнести к блюдам, топингам и тд)

```
struct Product {

    let img: UIImage
    let name: String
    let price: Int
    let type: String

}

var productsList = BasketModel.shared.records
var sections: [String] = ["Блюда","Топпинги","Напитки"]
var sectionedProducts: [[Product]] = []

// пусть type будет содержать имя секции
sections.forEach { section in
    let itemsInSection = productsList.filter { $0.type == section }
    sectionedProducts.append(itemsInSection)
}

// ...

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return sectionedProducts[section].count
}
```

Comment: Почему то выдает out of index все равно

Comment: @Moskwinow посмотрите в дебаггере что там вообще в массиве получается

Comment: В дебаггере я получаю всего навсего одно Value Блюда почему то

Comment: Сработало вроде как вот таким образом

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста у меня теперь ошибка индекса при удалении ячейки

Comment: @Moskwinow Если вы сделали как я предложил, то вы похоже удаляете данные для целой секции вместо одного ряда

Comment: Да спасибо за обширный ответ Все стработало как надо я забыл что при удалении нужно было написать секцию sectionedProducts[indexPath.section].remove(at: indexPath.row)